# I want my function to accept small and capital letters in python

Tags: python, case-sensitive

If I print a capital letter instead writing everything in small letters, the function doesn´t give me the correct output.

I would like to have the output "good bye", when I write: Quit quit QuIt

This is the Output right now if I take Quit or quit as an Input

> Quit

This is not a valid option. Please try again.

> quit

good bye

```
quit = True
​
help = ("""
start- to start the car
stop - to stop the car
quit - to exit
​
""")          
​
print(help)
while quit:
    operation = input(">")
    if operation == "start":
        print("Car started")
    elif operation == "stop":
        print("Car stopped")
    elif operation == "quit": 
        print("good bye")
        break
    else:
        print("This is not a valid option. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.lower()` function on the input string to transform your text into lowercase.

So use `operation = input(">").lower()`

[Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower) you can find a small docs

Answer (score 1):

Convert your input to lower case.

```
operation = input(">").lower()
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thank you for your help!